# API suddently started throwing Error: Access not granted or expired. Service_.getAccessToken Service.gs:466 error

Tags: rest, google-apps-script, salesforce

I am currently running some script on Google script to call the Salesforce REST API and download the data into Google Sheets.

I am using the Google Sheets library id `1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF`, which is the OAuth2 Library which can be found on [github here](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2).

I then, as instructed, use the following call to actually authenticate the Salesforce API with the following code:

```
var CLIENT_ID = {I get this from the connected SalesForce app};
var CLIENT_SECRET = {I get this from the connected SalesForce app};

function getService() {
  // Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
  // persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
  // scope of the property store.
  return OAuth2.createService('salesforce')
      // Set the endpoint URLs
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://flolive.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize')
      .setTokenUrl('https://flolive.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token')
      

      // Set the client ID and secret, from the Google Developers Console.
      .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
      .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)

      // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
      // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties())
       // .setCache(CacheService.getDocumentCache())
      // Set the scopes to request (space-separated for Google services).
    
     // .setScope('r_organization_social,r_basicprofile,r_liteprofile,rw_organization_admin,r_ads_reporting,r_ads')

      // Below are salesforce-specific OAuth2 parameters.

        .setParam('response_type', 'code')
      
      // Forces the approval prompt every time. This is useful for testing,
      // but not desirable in a production application.
      //.setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');
}

function authCallback(request) {
  var salesforceService = getService();
  var isAuthorized = salesforceService.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this tab.');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
  }
}

function logOut() {
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().deleteAllProperties();
  PropertiesService.getUserProperties().deleteAllProperties();
  var service=getService();
    service.reset();

}
function salesforceAPI() {
  var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    //exchange authorisation code for access token
    
    // sheet.getSheetByName('Settings').getRange(3,2).setValue(getService().getAccessToken());

    var tokenURL = 'https://flolive.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';

    var parameters = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code='+getService().getAccessToken()+'&redirect_uri='+getService().redirect_uri+'&client_id='+CLIENT_ID+'&client_secret='+CLIENT_SECRET;

 var options = {
   'method': 'POST',
   'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'muteHttpExceptions': true,    
   'payload': parameters
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(tokenURL,options);
  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  console.log(json);

    //sheet.getSheetByName('Settings').getRange(3,3).setValue(json.items);
  return json;

    
  } else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplate(
        '<a href="<?= authorizationUrl ?>" target="_blank">Authorize</a>. ' +
        'Reopen the sidebar when the authorization is complete.');
    template.authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl;
    var page = template.evaluate();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(page,'Authorise salesforce');

    Logger.log(getService().getAccessToken());
  }
}
```

Now I didn't have a problem with this. All the calls I made worked. I checked the callback url in the connected app, and everything was fine.

When I tried to output some of the data to a different worksheet, things stopped working.

So now I have 2 worksheets.

SF API Backend - This is where I put all the settings and references for the API
Logged Meetings - This is where I output the data that I'm trying to pull, which are the activities.

At first everything worked and I could output properly. However, when I added the API backend worksheet, at first it didn't work. I didn't get any errors, no data got pulled in.

I thought it was because it needed a different callback url, so I added it. Then, for some reason, I used the logOut() function mentioned above to try and reset the connection.
That's when I started getting this error **Error: Access not granted or expired.
Service_.getAccessToken @ Service.gs:466**.

I looked online and thought it had something to do with the `PropertyService`. So I deleted all the `PropertyService` keys. I even switched in the `getService()` function from `.setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties())` to `.setCache(CacheService.getDocumentCache())` (which is now commmented out).

Still the same error.

Then I went into Salesforce and get a set access token and replaced `+getService().getAccessToken()` with that.

I get this error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'setClientId' of undefined
at getService(SalesForceAuthentication:15:7)
at salesforceAPI(SalesForceAuthentication:56:17)**

I'm not sure why I get that error, since the code I changed wasn't even in that function.

And that's currently where I am.

I don't see anything blacklisted or any settings that would mess around or block this.

I even tried rebuilding the entire thing and then copying the code (only the code) to a different script. I got the same error **Error: Access not granted or expired.
Service_.getAccessToken @ Service.gs:466**.

This leads me to think that the Client Secret/Client Id is being blocked somehow.

Comment: About `When I tried to output some of the data to a different worksheet, things stopped working`, how are you executing this? Is this a script bound to a spreadsheet, and you copied that to another spreadsheet? Or is it an add-on? In any case, most likely the problem is that you are using `.setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties())`, so when you change the spreadsheet, that data doesn't persist. I don't think `.setCache(CacheService.getDocumentCache())` solves any of this.

Comment: Consider using `.setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())` or `.setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())` instead, which can persist on multiple documents (not sure if changing this will solve this, since I don't understand whether this is a bound script or something else).

Comment: @lamblichus it is a script that's attached to a particular spreadsheet and it's being executed either using a menu that I created used ``ui.createMenu``. Would disassociating it help? I'm still getting **TypeError: Cannot read property 'setClientId' of undefined**

Comment: @lamblichus, your solution worked. If you set it as the answer, I'll make it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

When you use [getDocumentProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getdocumentproperties) to store the authorization data:

> Gets a property store (for this script only) that all users can access **within the open document, spreadsheet, or form**

The data is not available if you use a different spreadsheet than the one where it was stored.

#### Solution:

If you want this to work for multiple spreadsheets, use [getScriptProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getscriptproperties) or [getUserProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getuserproperties) instead, which can persist on multiple documents (only if you're using the same script).

```
.setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
```

Comment: this was working for a little bit and then I started getting **INVALID_SESSION_ID Session expired or invalid** errors. I tried resetting the token by the logout script which is ``function logOut() {
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().deleteAllProperties();
  PropertiesService.getUserProperties().deleteAllProperties();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteAllProperties();

  var service=getService();
    service.reset();

  
}``

Comment: I tried hardcodding the initial access token from the app itself and got the same INVALID_SESSION_ID error as above.

Comment: @Jknight Can you still retrieve an access token from the service? If you use that to call the API in a different context, can you access it? Also, you are using the same script all the time, right?

Comment: I rewrote the code elsewhere and fixed up some errors and yes I could get the accesstoken, when running on a different project. I then took the access token and hardcoded that into the old script and it worked, but this isn't a long term solution

Comment: @Jknight Hi, I don't know what's going on here so it's just a guess, but have you added `setCache`? If that's the case, is it using the same scope as the property store? (user or script cache, user or script properties).

Comment: G'day @Iamblichus, I was actually going about this the wrong way. Apparently, SalesForce tokens need to be constantly refreshed. I found the answer in the question I posed here - [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/373168/access-rest-api-from-google-apps-script](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/373168/access-rest-api-from-google-apps-script)